# Inserting Script Tag using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I insert script tag below any div tag in html using this:

```
$("<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'></script>").html("").insertAfter($('#sidebar'));
```

I tried it but seems not working, not appearing in the page source.

Comment: Gotta break that closing `</script>` See [jQuery - Append JavaScript to a Div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961238/jquery-append-javascript-to-a-div)

Comment: You need to expand on "not working."  What doesn't work about it?

Comment: ...you want to include the jQuery library using jQuery?

Comment: Drop the `.html("")` Part

Comment: Incorrect "mark as duplicate" question. Reopening until someone (possibly me) finds a proper dupe for "loading jQuery using jQuery"

Comment: @Anonymous by not working i meant "not appearing in the page source below sidebar div

Comment: @Ali.NET Okay, include that in the question along with exactly what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: @billyonecan actually it is a product already have older version of jquery in its page and i want to insert the newer version using this approach, but but but below the specific div in body tag.

Comment: @Ali.NET Having two versions of jQuery is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol yeah i know. but anyway i want to use it for my existing code integration purpose.

Comment: @HerrSerker it still not appearing in page source after removing .html("")

Comment: @AlexK. sorry i didn't get you.

Comment: Press F12 and look for errors. When you have a problem with html/js, that should be step 1. When you post a question here, said errors should always be included in the question.

Comment: The method you likely should be using is `$.getScript(theurl)`, since appending it in a specific spot is pointless. However, i suggest NOT including a 2nd version of jquery, there's almost always a better way to handle this (such as simply using the older version until you can update the entire site to the newer version)

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `.html("")` and split the script tag otherwise it causes the browser to think you are closing the script tag you are working in. [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/r27w8/)

```
$("<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'></scr" + "ipt>").insertAfter($('#sidebar'));
```

** Solution requires the both the suggestions by @HerrSerker and @AlexK. to get it to work properly

Comment: Well, for the time being I had inserted the script in head tag using jQuery, but I will definitely give it a try soon. Thank you.